# Would unary negate operator come before the function call?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, operators, operator-precedence

I don't have a compiler handy but this is itching my curiosity. If I have code like this:

```
float a = 1;
float b = 2;

-a.add(b);
```

Would it be run as:

```
add(-a, b);
```

or

```
-add(a, b);
```

Comment: Just a simple return a + b function.

Comment: The latter. the application of negation is *after* the invocation (and summarily thrown away in this case).

Comment: Because you're not assigning it to anything. its like writing a single line in your c++ code like `-(a+b);`. There is no lvalue here. I.e. `x = -(a+b);` x is the lvalue.

Comment: I see what you mean. I was asking on the assumption that the code will execute, but good point.

Comment: Had you said a.add() actually performed (a+=b), i.e. accumulated the parameter b into the current value of a, it would make a difference, but that wasn't what you proposed.

Comment: ALmost *anything* can be a valid statement in C/C++; Assume `int x;`. Just `x;` is a perfectly valid (albeit meaningless) statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the fact that `float` doesn't have `add` method, of course, the second -- unless the language somehow knows the properties of the `add` function. Otherwise it can be plain wrong: imagine what would happen if you replace `-f(x)` with `f(-x)` for `f(x) = x * x`!

If however compiler knows that `add` is just an addition (for example, it *inlines* the function), it is allowed to choose whatever way it wants provided that the result stays unchanged.

For the expression `-a.add(b)`, definitely `(-a) + b` is different from `-(a + b)`, so the compiler will just choose the right one. According to the [precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), function call has higher priority, so `-(add(a, b))` will be chosen.

Answer (score 1):

The latter, because the sign matters when it comes to addition/subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you define something like `float add(float a, float b) { return a + b; }`, then it will be the second. Function calls have a higher operator precedence that unary minus, hence it would call the function, and then unary minus the result.